# 2 Conditional dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

District Master table:

[image]

District table:

[image]

[District Master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cyb0.jpg)
[District](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQHNK.jpg)

I have a form page in which there is a drop down called Category, In my district table i have district code saved and Category name. Based on the Category drop down selection in need to display district names present in District Master Table.... I'm Able to populate drop down, But when I do this I'm getting the district codes not the District Name....Somebody Please help!!!

My View Page:

```
   <select name="category" id="category">
   <option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
   <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
   <option value="Category 3">Category 3</option>
   </select>

   <select name="placename" id="placename">
   <option value="">Please select a Place</option>  
   </select>
```

Controller:

```
    public function ajax_place_list() 
     { 
     $this->load->helper('url'); 
     $this->load->model('JcMeetingExpense_model'); 
     $data['district'] = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model->getplace(); 
     echo json_encode($data);
     }
```

Model:

```
     function getplace()
      { 
      $this->db->where('district_code',$this->input->post('category'));
      $query = $this->db->get('district');
      return $query->result(); 
      }
```

Script

```
    <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#category").on('change', function() {
     var category= $(this).val();

     if(category){
       $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'JcMeetingExpense/ajax_place_list',
        data: { category: category},
        success : function(response) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(response);
            $('#placename').val(response.district); 

        },error:function(e){
        alert("error");}
         });
        }
     });
     });

  </script>
```

Comment: add images into the question instead of external image link and also show your code

Comment: I have edited my Question pls have a look

Comment: i have add answer and if you have more query then tell me

Answer (score 1):

i think in `district` table column (`district`) similar to `district master` table column (`district_code`) then

use inner join with district master table in model

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('district');
$this->db->join('District_Master', 'district.district= District_Master.district_code');
$this->db->where('district.district_code',$this->input->post('category'));
$query = $this->db->get();
```

using this query you can get name from `district_master` table and you can used name in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use ajax to get district name just and an listen even like on change or blur on the catagory drop down when you get the values from db for example you have used a query like this in model part

```
function getplace()
      { 
        $this->db->where('district_code',$this->input->post('category'));
        $this->db->join('District_Master', 'district.district= District_Master.district_code');//added this
        $this->db->select("District_Master.district_name");//add this
        $this->db->from("district");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result(); 
      }
```

then for the dropdown of district use

```
<select><option value="//call district_code here "> //call district_name here</option></select>
```

call the above thing with your object since you said that you have populated the data in dropdown this can be one of the error try and comment if any error